# GDAL & Python 3 environment variable

Tags: gdal, mac, python-3

Newbie here. I've just loaded OSX Catalina on my iMac. I've installed GDAL 2.4 complete from the Kyngchaos site. The install works great for all GDAL commands except for the python ones (gdal_polygonize.py for example). Then I get this error:

```
-bash: /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/gdal_polygonize.py:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

The python version I'm running is python 3.7.5

In my system there is no /Library/Frameworks/Python.frameworks folder. Instead, it seems to be here:
`/usr/local/bin/python3.7`

However, my PATH variable includes this folder:

```
/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/Programs:/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Programs:/Library/Frameworks/UnixImageIO.framework/Programs:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

What am I doing wrong? how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same issue as well. After I downloaded and installed python using 
the [macOS 64-bit installer for 3.6.5](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/python-3.6.5-macosx10.9.pkg) from https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/ , python was installed in the location `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6`